# Change MySQL database column to accept handle links to webpages

Tags: html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have setup the links to be clickable in the access file to upload via ODBC to PhpMyAdmin into my MySQL database.  But the links are not clickable once they get into the sql database.  How do I make the column in the table clickable?  I access the tables through PhpMyAdmin (I do not know how to write php code or understand how to do it) but I need one column in my database to accept the urls and be clickable when the database is queried

Comment: i dont think phpmyadmin could do that.

Comment: I can access the table structure but I don't know how to make the column accept the link.  I really need to get this figured out ASAP

Comment: I desparately need someone to tell me how I can make the links clickable whether it is to use a different means of uploading to PhpMyAdmin on my cPanel or a way to make the links clickable in the current way I am doing this.  I do not know how to do the coding so if there is someone who would like to help with that, I would really appreciate any help I can get

Comment: Using phpmyadmin I have seen "clickable" links appear in the result tables if the columns are inter-table relations, foreign keys, to other tables.  Having arbitrary clickable links in phpmyadmin would require either: hacking phpmyadmin or submitting a "request for enhancement" to the makers of phpmyadmin and waiting on their response.  I am just going to guess that you want to build your own web based display app that can change the urls in your table to links.

Comment: You cannot make column content clickable in a database table you can format the selected columns into clickable html tags based on the data. However not inside PhpMyAdmin